# Доброго времени суток, столкнулся с проблемой, код не работает, выдает ошибку (cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (1,3,1000))

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, tensorflow, keras, искусственный-интеллект

Я не спец в keras и tf, пытался загрузить модель и запустить ее, но столкнулся с проблемой, не корректной обработкой входных данных. Сама нейронка обучена и сохранена, нацелена на продолжение строчки по первым словам.

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, SimpleRNN, Input, Embedding
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer, text_to_word_sequence
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
maxWordsCount = 1000
inp_words = 3

model = Sequential()


model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam')
model = keras.models.load_model('Absolute11')
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=maxWordsCount, filters='!–"—#$%&amp;()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n\r«»',
                      lower=True, split=' ', char_level=False)

def buildPhrase(texts, str_len=20):
    res = texts
    data = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(texts)
    for i in range(str_len):
        x = to_categorical(data[i: i + inp_words], num_classes=maxWordsCount)  # преобразуем в One-Hot-encoding
        inp = x.reshape(1, inp_words, maxWordsCount)

        pred = model.predict(inp)
        indx = pred.argmax(axis=1)[0]
        data.append(indx)

        res += " " + tokenizer.index_word[indx]  # дописываем строку

    return res


res = buildPhrase("позитив добавляет годы")
print(res)
```